# Is the Intel Galileo Gen 2 supported by Windows Developer Program for IoT

Tags: intel-galileo, windowsondevices

Now that the Galileo has been updated by Intel to Gen 2 (https://www-ssl.intel.com/content/www/us/en/do-it-yourself/galileo-maker-quark-board.html) is this (or will it be) a supported device by Microsoft for the Windows Developer Program for IoT?

Comment: From https://ms-iot.github.io/content/IBoughtAGalileo.htm "The version of Microsoft Windows released for the Windows Developer Program for IoT requires an Intel Galileo Gen 1 with 1.0.2 firmware. Gen 2 of the Galileo is not supported by this release."

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a discussion to [IRC](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=windowsondevices) or [twitter](https://twitter.com/hashtag/winbuilder) to provide input into which boards we should support (one of our primary goals is engaging the community to understand what you would like to see us support).

That said we are definitely working with Intel to identify which boards we should support moving forward and the Galileo Gen 2 is definitely part of this discussion. We have nothing to announce yet, but expect more information from us over the coming weeks as we get feedback from the community.

Pranish, Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

The Windows IOT doesn't "support" the Galileo Gen2 yet but I can verify that it runs on the Gen 2 in my experience.  I followed the same instructions on the site they give for the Gen 1.

Answer (score 0):

October 2nd, 2014 post in the Building Apps for Windows Blog...

[IoT Developer Program Update: Support for Intel Galileo Gen 2 Boards](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/02/iot-developer-program-update-support-for-intel-galileo-gen-2-boards/)

What's available is variously described as a "preview image" and "alpha release".